# JMeter Master Very Slow to Finish (3 minute hold, followed by 5 minutes of ???)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm encountering some weird behavior at the end of my jmeter tests.

I'm using Master-Slave with 4 slaves running on 4 separate VMs hosted on another box.

The test runs fine for the "Hold" period, 3 minutes for this test. But then it just sits there for about 5 minutes occasionally reporting a handful responses have come in even though all the threads have "Finished."

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t /root/wordpress32sites_url2.jmx -l csvfilename -e -o htmlfoldername -R jmeter01,jmeter02,jmeter03,jmeter04
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /root/wordpress32sites_url2.jmx
Configuring remote engine: jmeter01
Configuring remote engine: jmeter02
Configuring remote engine: jmeter03
Configuring remote engine: jmeter04
Starting remote engines
Starting the test @ Fri Mar 01 17:25:07 PST 2019 (1551489907760)
Remote engines have been started
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary +  12305 in 00:00:18 =  695.3/s Avg:    85 Min:    23 Max:   560 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 320 Started: 288 Finished: 0
summary +  49400 in 00:00:30 = 1648.4/s Avg:   322 Min:    26 Max:  7698 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 640 Started: 608 Finished: 0
summary =  61705 in 00:00:48 = 1294.5/s Avg:   275 Min:    23 Max:  7698 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +  48300 in 00:00:30 = 1607.5/s Avg:   402 Min:    28 Max: 10509 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 640 Started: 608 Finished: 0
summary = 110005 in 00:01:18 = 1415.5/s Avg:   331 Min:    23 Max: 10509 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +  48200 in 00:00:30 = 1603.1/s Avg:   404 Min:    32 Max:  9567 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 640 Started: 608 Finished: 0
summary = 158205 in 00:01:48 = 1467.9/s Avg:   353 Min:    23 Max: 10509 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +  47100 in 00:00:30 = 1574.4/s Avg:   415 Min:    33 Max: 10351 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 640 Started: 608 Finished: 0
summary = 205305 in 00:02:18 = 1491.0/s Avg:   367 Min:    23 Max: 10509 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +  48400 in 00:00:30 = 1615.0/s Avg:   403 Min:    33 Max: 10830 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 640 Started: 608 Finished: 0
summary = 253705 in 00:02:48 = 1513.2/s Avg:   374 Min:    23 Max: 10830 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +  46500 in 00:00:30 = 1546.4/s Avg:   412 Min:    32 Max: 10453 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 324 Started: 608 Finished: 316
summary = 300205 in 00:03:18 = 1518.2/s Avg:   380 Min:    23 Max: 10830 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +   3717 in 00:05:01 =   12.3/s Avg:   384 Min:    29 Max:  8782 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 608 Finished: 640
summary = 303922 in 00:08:19 =  608.8/s Avg:   380 Min:    23 Max: 10830 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +     87 in 00:00:00 = 7909.1/s Avg:   473 Min:    36 Max:  5197 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 608 Finished: 640
summary = 304009 in 00:08:19 =  608.9/s Avg:   380 Min:    23 Max: 10830 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up remote @ Fri Mar 01 17:33:31 PST 2019 (1551490411593)
... end of run
Creating summariser <summary>
```

The JMeter slaves report nothing of interest:

```
./jmeter-server
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[10.1.1.28:21458,SSLRMIServerSocketFactory(host=jmeter09.ovirt.pb.lab/10.1.1.28, keyStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi),SSLRMIClientSocketFactory(keyStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi)](local),objID:[-5880d2c8:169394dd3fb:-7fff, -3132663786122032135]]]
Starting the test on host jmeter09 @ Fri Mar 01 12:54:27 UTC 2019 (1551444867945)
Finished the test on host jmeter09 @ Fri Mar 01 13:02:52 UTC 2019 (1551445372516)
```

If I interrupt the test on the Master the slaves keep "running the test" for those last 5 minutes(after the actual 3.5 minutes it should have run) before I can use them again.

Here are the details I mentioned above in the JMX file:

```
        <stringProp name="TargetLevel">5</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="RampUp">0.5</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Steps">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Hold">3</stringProp>
```

I think this is an unrelated note but:
Other than the above, the test runs perfectly fine though it reports I have more "Active" threads then "Started" -- it doesn't seem to actually impact the testing and appears to be changed by the RampUp time (it's 0.5 below). 0 RampUp time results in only 320 started, and a RampUp of 1 shows all as started.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that all the nodes (client and servers):

1. Are running exactly the same version of JMeter.
2. Are using the same version of Java on all systems. Using different versions of Java may work but is discouraged.

Second, check the [sampler sender properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode):

> Listeners in the test plan send their results back to the client JMeter which writes the results to the specified files By default, samples are sent back synchronously as they are generated.
>   This can affect the maximum throughput of the server test; the sample result has to be sent back before the thread can continue. There are some JMeter properties that can be set to alter this behaviour.

Default sample sending mode (since 2.9) is `StrippedBatch` — remove responseData from successful samples, and use `Batch` sender to send them.
The `Batch` sender send saved samples when either the count (`num_sample_threshold`) or time (`time_threshold`) exceeds a threshold, at which point the samples are sent synchronously.

The thresholds can be configured on the server using the following properties:

- `num_sample_threshold` — number of samples to accumulate, default 100.
- `time_threshold` — time threshold, default 60000 ms = 60 seconds.

So, check this propertie's values.

Other way to scale your test - to [run JMeter tests in a cloud service](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2015/06/jmeter-scaling/).